# How can I get back to multiple tmux panes once I suddenly type `prefix + enter`?

Tags: tmux

In tmux, I have a problem.
I was working in multiple panes by splitting the entire terminal into 2 or 3, so that I could switch over different tasks with a few types, which was great.
However, I accidentally typed `prefix + enter` which maximizes the one pane so that it occupies the entire terminal.
This cannot be killed since it is running experimental code.
How can I switch back to other panes?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you zoom in and out from panes by

prefix + <kbd>z</kbd>

where prefix, is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> by default